# How to fix missing Wireless applet on Debian 8 Gnome Desktop Environment?

Tags: debian, gnome

i have installed a 64 bit live Debian 8 Gnome desktop environment on virtual box for testing purposes so later I can do a hard disk install on laptop i can see a wired network manager, but i cant see a wireless applet on network display, can anybody suggest me how to fix this ?

Regards

Comment: May be : -> Add -> Wireless -> and convert your IP modem -> in IPV4 or IPV6. I'm D8-KDE but I think it's the same protocol !

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is presenting the guest OS (Debian 8) with a wired network interface, not a wireless one. I don't think you can make it also present a wireless one.

Note that a virtualization program abstracts away a lot of the actual hardware details. It is not at all a good test of "will this run on this machine?". Instead, you should just boot from the live DVD/USB stick/etc. The point of a live image is that you can run it from the live media without touching your existing OS install on the hard disk.

Comment: i installed it on a live usb, there is no wireless applet showing, its only showing wired connection nothing else. what should i do now ??